# How to describe a function returning an array consists of 3 elements of different types

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I'm writing a middleware helper function which returns an array containing 3 elements:

1. Is either `Server` or `IncomingMessage`
2. Is either `ServerResponse` or null
3. Always a `Function`

The helper function is something like this:

```js
function getCallbackParts(args) {
    return [
        args[0],
        args.length === 3 ? args[1] : null,
        args.length === 3 ? args[2] : args[1]
    ];
}
```

So, later in code, I do something like this:

```js
function MyMiddleware() {
    const [request, response, next] = getCallbackParts(arguments);

    request.transportType = request.hasOwnProperty('rooms') ? 'socket.io' : 'http';

    next();
}
```

I have no problems with executing the code, but I need to document `getCallbackParts` returning result, so my IDE (I use WebStorm) will automatically treat `request` like it either `Server` or `IncomingMessage`.

I tried this (variant 1, merged variants which produce the same result):

```js
/**
 * @return [Server|IncomingMessage, ServerResponse|null, Function]
 * @return [(Server|IncomingMessage), (ServerResponse|null), Function]
 * @return {[Server|IncomingMessage, ServerResponse|null, Function]}
 * @return {[(Server|IncomingMessage), (ServerResponse|null), Function]}
 */
```

But this way my IDE shows that the `request` can be `Server`, `IncomingMessage`, `ServerResponse`, `null`, or `Function`. The same for `response` and for `next`.

I also tried this (variant 2, merged two variants which produce the same result):

```js
/**
 * @return {Array<(Server|IncomingMessage), (ServerResponse|null), Function>}
 * @return {Array.<(Server|IncomingMessage), (ServerResponse|null), Function>}
 */
```

This way, the `request` is detected correctly, but `response` and `next` also inherit `Server|IncomingMessage` type for some reason.

How to write a correct jsDoc return type in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```js
/**
 * @return {{0: Server|IncomingMessage, 1: ServerResponse|null, 2: Function}}
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping with parentheses.

```
/**
 * @return {[(Server|IncomingMessage), (ServerResponse|null), Function]}
 */
```

Comment: I tried this also (and updated "variant 1" in my question to show what I was trying). This way IDE shows that the request can be `Server`, `IncomingMessage`, `ServerResponse`, `null`, or `Function`.